# not able to zoom at current location in google maps android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Below is the code for map activity, i am not able to zoom at current location.I want that when a user opens the app, map should gets zooms at the current location.Please correct me where i am wrong.

Thanks

```
public class MapActivity extends BaseActivty implements
        OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private static String TAG = "MAP LOCATION";
    Context mContext;
    TextView mLocationMarkerText;
    private LatLng mCenterLatLong;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    private AddressResultReceiver mResultReceiver;
    private ImageView mMarker;
    DatabaseReference databaseMediCare;

    protected String mAddressOutput;
    protected String mAreaOutput;
    protected String mCityOutput;
    protected String mStateOutput;
    EditText mLocationAddress;
    TextView mLocationText;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        mContext = this;
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(map);

        mLocationMarkerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);
        mLocationAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Address);
        mMarker= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageMarker);
          mLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Locality);

        mLocationText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                openAutocompleteActivity();

            }

        });
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler());

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            // If this check succeeds, proceed with normal processing.
            // Otherwise, prompt user to get valid Play Services APK.
            if (!AppUtils.isLocationEnabled(mContext)) {
                // notify user
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                dialog.setMessage("Location not enabled!");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Open location settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Location not supported in this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

      }



    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnMapReady");
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                //Log.d("Camera postion change" + "", cameraPosition + "");
                mCenterLatLong = cameraPosition.target;
                String fullAddress = "";

                mMap.clear();

                try {

                    Location mLocation = new Location("");
                    mLocation.setLatitude(mCenterLatLong.latitude);
                    mLocation.setLongitude(mCenterLatLong.longitude);
                    startIntentService(mLocation);
                    // handleNewLocation(mLocation);
                    getCurrentLocation();
                    fullAddress =getCompleteAddressString(mLocation.getLatitude(),mLocation.getLongitude());
                    mLocationMarkerText.setText(fullAddress);
                    //mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + mCenterLatLong.latitude + "," + "Long : " + mCenterLatLong.longitude);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
//        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
//        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
//
//        // Add a marker in current location and move the camera

    }




    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            changeMap(mLastLocation);
            Log.d(TAG, "ON connected");

        } else
            try {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                        mGoogleApiClient, this);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        try {
            if (location != null)
                changeMap(location);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                //finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void changeMap(Location location) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Reaching map" + mMap);


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }



        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            LatLng latLong;
            String fullAddress = "";

            latLong = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(latLong).zoom(19f).tilt(0).build();

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            //mMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(20.5937,78.9629) , 19f) );

            mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + location.getLatitude() + "," + "Long : " + location.getLongitude());
            fullAddress =getCompleteAddressString(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
            mLocationMarkerText.setText(fullAddress);
            startIntentService(location);
            // showToast("hii" + getCompleteAddressString(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }



    /**
     * Receiver for data sent from FetchAddressIntentService.
     */

    class AddressResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
        public AddressResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }


        /**
         * Receives data sent from FetchAddressIntentService and updates the UI in MainActivity.
         */

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

            // Display the address string or an error message sent from the intent service.
            mAddressOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RESULT_DATA_KEY);

            mAreaOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_AREA);

            mCityOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_CITY);
            mStateOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_STREET);

            displayAddressOutput();

            // Show a toast message if an address was found.
            if (resultCode == AppUtils.LocationConstants.SUCCESS_RESULT) {
                //  showToast(getString(R.string.address_found));


            }


        }

    }


    /**
     * Updates the address in the UI.
     */

    protected void displayAddressOutput() {
        // mLocationAddressTextView.setText(mAddressOutput);
        try {
            if (mAreaOutput != null)
                mLocationText.setText(mAreaOutput+ "");

            mLocationAddress.setText(mAddressOutput);
            mLocationText.setText(mAreaOutput);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Creates an intent, adds location data to it as an extra, and starts the intent service for
     * fetching an address.
     */

    protected void startIntentService(Location mLocation) {
        // Create an intent for passing to the intent service responsible for fetching the address.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);

        // Pass the result receiver as an extra to the service.
        intent.putExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);

        // Pass the location data as an extra to the service.
        intent.putExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, mLocation);

        // Start the service. If the service isn't already running, it is instantiated and started
        // (creating a process for it if needed); if it is running then it remains running. The
        // service kills itself automatically once all intents are processed.
        startService(intent);
    }


    private void openAutocompleteActivity() {
        try {
            // The autocomplete activity requires Google Play Services to be available. The intent
            // builder checks this and throws an exception if it is not the case.
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                    .build(this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            // Indicates that Google Play Services is either not installed or not up to date. Prompt
            // the user to correct the issue.
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, e.getConnectionStatusCode(),
                    0 /* requestCode */).show();
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // Indicates that Google Play Services is not available and the problem is not easily
            // resolvable.
            e.printStackTrace();
            String message = "Google Play Services is not available: " +
                    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(e.errorCode);

            Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Called after the autocomplete activity has finished to return its result.
     */

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Check that the result was from the autocomplete widget.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the user's selected place from the Intent.
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(mContext, data);

                // TODO call location based filter


                LatLng latLong;


                latLong = place.getLatLng();

                mLocationText.setText(place.getName() + "");

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(latLong).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();


                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


            }


        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(mContext, data);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Indicates that the activity closed before a selection was made. For example if
            // the user pressed the back button.
        }
    }
    private String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {
        String strAdd = "";
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
            if (addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

                for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }
                strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                //Log.w("My Current loction address", "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());
            } else {
//                Log.w("My Current loction address", "No Address returned!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
//            Log.w("My Current loction address", "Canont get Address!");
        }
        return strAdd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in onMap() Ready.

```
 Location loc = mGoogleMap.getMyLocation();
                LatLng currentLoc = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLoc,17.0f));
```

Updated :

```
getMyLocation() is deprecated. so use LocationClient instead
```

Comment: getMyLocation is depricated.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the code below:

```
LatLng latLong = new 
  LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLong, 13));
```

Comment: its zooms, but not at current location.

Comment: Pass your current location latLng, it will definately zoom.

Answer (score 0):

**animateCamera** will animate the camera to the desired position with a smooth animation, while **moveCamera** will move the camera to the desired position instantly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use moveCamera method of googleMap

Here is an example

```
 LatLng locationPos = new LatLng(lat, lon);
 map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(locationPos, 12));
```